# how can i change format from text to number and tel?

Tags: javascript, html

so i fetch value from textfile to show in textbox but i want to change value from textfile to be tel
and number it is possible to change format value?

(i have 2 textfile) teltext.txt include one phone number (8769382349) amounttext.txt include one price (59)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
      
      fetch('teltext.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(tel => {
       document.getElementById('gen-user').value = tel;
       });
       fetch('amounttext.txt').then(response => response.text()).then(number => {
       document.getElementById('gen-amount').value = number;
       });
</script>

<input type="tel" class="form-control"
                        name="user" id="gen-user"
                        ng-model="user" ng-minlength="10" required>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control"
                        min="0" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*"                     
                        name="amount" id="gen-amount"
                        ng-model="amount">
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the output from .txt file in text format

```
const phoneNumberText = "8769382349";
const amountText = "59";
```

We can convert text into number using `Number` property

`console.log(Number(phoneNumberText)); // output will be 8769382349`
`console.log(Number(amountText)); // output will be 59`

Comment: Thankyou for answer but when change value in txt file i want "const phoneNumbertext" to change value like txt file automatic too or its is possible var or const read value from txt file?

Comment: yes we can read value from txt file using javascript read file function